# Error using ksoap

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ksoap

I have implemented many SOAP functions for my app, but now I have some problems with this one:

```
public int generatePost(String sid, int uid, int obj_id, int ref_id, int thr_pk, 
        String msg, int pos_pk, String title, String date)
{
    int pos_pk_new = 0;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject("urn:ilUserAdministration", "generatePost");
    soapObject.addProperty("sid", sid);
    soapObject.addProperty("uid", uid);
    soapObject.addProperty("obj_id", obj_id);
    soapObject.addProperty("ref_id", ref_id);
    soapObject.addProperty("thr_pk", thr_pk);
    soapObject.addProperty("msg", msg);
    soapObject.addProperty("pos_pk", pos_pk);
    soapObject.addProperty("title", title);
    soapObject.addProperty("date", date);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(PATH_TO_YOUR_ILIAS_INSTALLATION + "/webservice/soap/server.php");
    transport.debug = true;
    try
    {
        transport.call("generatePost", envelope);
        pos_pk_new = Integer.parseInt(envelope.getResponse().toString());
        return pos_pk_new;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {               e.printStackTrace();            }
    catch (XmlPullParserException e)
    {               e.printStackTrace();            }

    return 0;
}
```

Parameters like: PATH_TO_YOUR_ILIAS_INSTALLATION, urn:ilUserAdministration, etc are fine. I have other functions that work good, but this one is generating this error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG (empty) <br>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44c45f52) 
0
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(Unknown Source)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(Unknown Source)
    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(Unknown Source)
    at de.ilias.SOAPExample.generatePost(SOAPExample.java:1048)
    at de.ilias.SOAPExample.main(SOAPExample.java:1473)
```

The php function generatePost is working good because I have tested it in a php snippet.

Is it possible that ksoap library have a limit of parameters to add to my soapObject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was fine, I just forgot to add a library in my soap function... One day trying to solve the problem and that was. It's solved.